# How to update all data by repository (laravel 5.3)?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, repository, laravel-5.3

My repository is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Models\UsersBank;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container;
use Rinvex\Repository\Repositories\EloquentRepository;
class UserBankRepository extends EloquentRepository
{
    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {

        $this->setContainer($container)
             ->setModel(UsersBank::class)
             ->setRepositoryId('rinvex.repository.uniqueid');
    }
}
```

My model is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class UsersBank extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','bank_id','status','account_name','account_number'];
}
```

My service is like this :

```
public function setMain($id)
{
    $param['status'] = 1;
    $this->user_bank_repository->update($id, $param);
}
```

When setMain function executed, It will update field status = 1 by the id

I want to update status = 1 to all record. So, Not by id

How can I do it?

**Note :**

Update which I mean here is the update via the repository. Not update through a model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the source code of [`update()`](https://github.com/rinvex/repository/blob/master/src/Repositories/EloquentRepository.php#L226) method of the package and you'll see it's impossible, so you'll need to use `foreach()` and create a bunch of queries.

My opinion is this and similar packages are useless since they are still using Eloquent and do not provide any handful functionality. I'd recommend you to use Eloquent directly to update all rows with just one query:

```
Model::query()->update(['status' => 1]);
```